# I want to copy value of a set of text boxes to another textbox using a checkbox But there is something wrong and it doesn't even throws any error

Tags: jquery

**     I want to copy value of a set of text boxes to another set textbox using a checkbox But there is something wrong and it doesn't even throws any error. Please Help!!!!**

```
<div class="regidiv">
    <input type="checkbox" id="AddressCheckBox" class="checkbox-inline"/>

    <p> *Check this box if Mailing Address and Delivery Address are the same</p><br/>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#AddressCheckBox").click(copy());

        function copy() {
            if ($("#AddressCheckBox").is(":checked")) {
                var OrganizationName = $("#OrganizationName").val();
                var Division = $("#Division").val();
                var Department = $("#Department").val();
                var BuildingRoom = $("#BuildingRoom").val();
                var Street = $("#Street").val();
                var City = $("#City").val();
                var PoBox = $("#PoBox").val();
                var Province = $("#Province").val();
                var Country = $("#Country").val();

                $("#DOrganizationName").val(OrganizationName);
                $("#DDivision").val(Division);
                $("#DDepartment").val(Department);
                $("#DBuildingRoom").val(BuildingRoom);
                $("#DStreet").val(Street);
                $("#DCity").val(City);
                $("#DPoBox").val(PoBox);
                $("#DProvince").val(Province);
                $("#DCountry").val(Country);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try "copy()" without parenthesis like ".click(copy);"

Comment: try to add console.log or alert in click event to check whether click event is calling or not

Comment: at first place function `copy` before bind event click. and, yes, pass handle as function `$("#AddressCheckBox").click(copy);` without parenthesis.

Comment: @Virendrayadav The event is wired up it shows the alert box upon clicking.  I have tried removing the paranthesis but it doesnot show the values of these textboxes into others

Comment: try alert inside is(":checked") condition it is firing or not and if yes then also check values set in variable or not

Comment: Yes the alert is firing inside the (":checked") condition and no there are no values set in variables

Comment: cross check the ids for all textbox which you are using

Comment: or you can try alert($("#OrganizationName").size()); this will alert the number of controls with this id in your page so you can cross check why jquery selector not working

Comment: is it all the textboxes are  ASP.NET TextBox Controls??

Comment: I used the alert you just asked me to and it returns zero. I have also cross checked the ID's of the The ASP.NET Textboxes i have on my page. but it still doesn't work

Comment: It worked with simple HTML input tags. Thanks For your Help Though :)

Answer (score 0):

use

`$("#AddressCheckBox").change(copy());`

instead of

`$("#AddressCheckBox").click(copy());`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:
HTML:

```
<div class="mailing-address">
    <input type="text" id="OrganizationName" />
    <input type="text" id="Division" />
    <input type="text" id="Department" />
    <input type="text" id="BuildingRoom" />
</div>

<div class="delivery-address">
    <input type="text" id="DOrganizationName" />
    <input type="text" id="DDivision" />
    <input type="text" id="DDepartment" />
    <input type="text" id="DBuildingRoom" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#AddressCheckBox").on('click', function() {

        if ($("#AddressCheckBox").is(":checked")) {

            $('.mailing-address input').each(function(index, element) {

                var duplicateId = '#D' + $(element).attr('id'),
                    $dupElement = $(duplicateId);

                if($dupElement.length == 1) {
                    $dupElement.val($(element).val());
                }
            });
        } else {
             $('.delivery-address input').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14u57v0c/1/)
 [JSfiddle (data-* attribute usage)](https://jsfiddle.net/14u57v0c/3/)

Comment: I am using server side text boxes! what changes should i make into the above function to make that work

Comment: you can place some identifiers into the data-attributes, e.g. <input type="text" data-identifier="OrganizationName" /> and then you can find duplicate by attribute selector $('[data-identifier="d' + $(element).data().identifier + '"]') or, if structure is the same, you can even use indexes